# Import a csv file and convert to a Dataframe with Special Format

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

What is the best Python way to convert a list of data into a Dataframe so that I can do finance analysis.

I have a fund.csv file as following:

[image]

I want to read the file and convert to the format like this:

[image]

I wrote the simple code:

```
import csv
with open("fund.csv", "r") as csv_file:

csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
for lines in csv_reader:
    if "20-" in lines[0]:
        print(lines[0])
```

I can read the csv file and print the list of date, but don't know how to convert the whole list into above data frame table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As we encountered similar data format issue in other fields, which is not limited to finance. It is important to find a good solution especially for big data analysis.

Thanks for those who have joined us to tackle the challenging issue today. I am honored and blessed to put forward with my answer in this StackOverflow platform, which may not be the perfect one, but help me a lot and saved time to handle bigger datasets. Hope you find it is helpful too. If you have a better comprehensive solution, we would appreciate if you can share.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
fund = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','V1', 'V2','Rate'])
with open("Fund.csv", "r") as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
n=0
m=0
for lines in csv_reader:
    if "20-" in lines[0]:
        n=n+1
        m=0
        Date = lines
        #fund = pd.DataFrame({"Date":Date, "Day":n})
    else:
        m=m+1
        if m ==1: 
            v1 = lines
        elif m == 2: 
            v2 = lines
        else:
            rate = lines
            fund = pd.DataFrame({"Date":Date, "V1":v1, "V2":v2, "Rate": rate})
            print(fund)
```

The output is:

[image]

Regards and Have a nice day.